# How do i set a page as my homepage?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Page "mydomain.com/wordpress/calientes/" that i want to set as my Main/homepage so when an user go to mydomain.com they can actually see "mydomain.com/wordpress/calientes/" displaying only mydomain.com on the navigator... like 9gag.com does... you go to their website  and their main page is actually 9gag.com/hot but you only see 9gag.com on the navigator window  unless you click on the "Hot" menu.. you'll see 9gag.com/hot.

I'm playing around with .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress/calientes/ [L]
```

But it's not working...

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not play any codes to do so. In Settings section of your Wp-admin you can set / or say you can select any predefined or published page/post as front page.

Let me be more clear regarding url structure type you need to follow :

http://xyz.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php

There you will have option to :  **"Front page displays"**

You can select **"A static page (select below)"**   Any desired page /Post As main front page...

Hope you get the point & problem gets resolved .

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be as simple as a rewrite rule. This is because wordpress has its own routing and expects to see path information from either the `REQUEST_URI` or path info. That means if you try to rewrite, the path info isn't going to be right.

The way I've set this up in the past is create an `index.php` file in your document root and add this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And in the `index.php`:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./wordpress/calientes/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

not a `.htaccess` answer, but you can use sql for this

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 2 WHERE `option_name` = 'page_on_front';
```

just replace `option_value` with the id of your new homepage. Dirty but effective.